# Событие с одинаковым классом

Tags: jquery

Есть такая разметка.

```
<div class="blockFilter">
   <h3 class="title">
      Тип изделия                
   </h3>
   <div class="variants">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="attr_1_1" value="1"> 1                        </label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="attr_1_2" value="2"> 2                        </label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="attr_1_3" value="3"> 3                        </label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="attr_1_4" value="4"> 4                       </label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="attr_1_5" value="5"> 5                        </label>
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Блок `blockFilter` повторяется много раз, с разными параметрами.
Как сделать так, что бы при нажатие на `class="title"` открывалось и закрывалость(`slideUp - slideDowm`) блок variants, но только в этом `blockFilter` в котором мы кликнули.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В событие `onclick` приходит контекст `this` - это элемент, по которому кликнули. Вам нужно взять следующий элемент от `this`. Для этого есть метод `next()`

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.variants').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: странно, что то не работает(((

Comment: Отчего же не работает? http://jsbin.com/katizinogu

Comment: Мистика, но через siblings работает, а через next нет. Все ровно приму как правильный